# Is there any easy way to do this divergence problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This problem is ugly. I would like to see a nice insightful way of doing it without just doing a huge ugly computation.

$\text{div}((\nabla u)u) = \text{tr}(\nabla u \nabla u) + u \cdot \nabla \text{div}(u)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ugly at all, if you try to prove the correct identity. Note that $u$ is a scalar function; whence ${\rm div}(u)$ makes no sense. The correct formula is
$${\rm div}(u\>\nabla u)=|\nabla u|^2+u\>{\rm div}(\nabla u)\ .$$ The formula immediately follows from
$$(u\>u_x)_x=u_x^2+ u\>u_{xx}\ ,$$
and similarly for the derivatives with respect to $y$ and $z$.

Comment: I don't know the conventions in force in your formula when $u$ is a vector.